# In "Once upon a tower" how do I achieve the challenge "Hit a falling Wild Pig from below"?

Tags: once-upon-a-tower

I have been trying for a week to achieve this challenge but I can't. I tried hitting the square below a pig and then hitting the pig but it's not that. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As what in the challenge says you just need to hit the pig when it is falling from you. You are below the pig not sideward but below. I have finished that challenge so i know and if you didnt work, just try it again and again.